# Theme user registration page in Drupal 6 with an Omega subtheme

Tags: drupal, templates, overriding

I´ve found numerous tutorials on how to do this on D6, BUT, it seems that the example code I´ve found doesn´t quite work on Omega subtheme.

Here´s the code I´ve found it suits me best ([via Trellon](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/theming-user-register-form-d6)):

Inside template.tpl.php:

```
<?php
function themename_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    ...
    // tell Drupal what template to use for the user register form
    'user_register' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'user-register', // this is the name of the template
    ),
    ...
  );
}
?>
```

And here´s the user-register.tpl.php form:

```
<div id="registration_form">
  <div class="field">
    <?php
      print drupal_render($form['account']['name']); // prints the username field
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
      print drupal_render($form['account']['pass']); // print the password field
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
        print drupal_render($form['submit']); // print the submit button
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thing is that inside my template.tpl.php file I´ve already declared mytheme_theme, so I don´t know how to add the new code.

Inside My omega subtheme folder:

```
/**
 * Implementation of HOOK_theme().
 */
function lcph_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks = omega_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path);
  // Add your theme hooks like this:
  /*
  $hooks['hook_name_here'] = array( // Details go here );
  */
  // @TODO: Needs detailed comments. Patches welcome!
  return $hooks;

}
```

In fact, if I just copy/paste the code inside my template file, this is the error I´ve got:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare lcph_theme() (previously declared in /sites/all/themes/lcph/template.php:22) in /sites/all/themes/lcph/template.php on line 125
```

How could I add the example code inside my omega subtheme template?
Thanks for your guidance and help!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont add any thing to template.php file unless you search in your template.php file for omega_theme() function if you found it then modify it...if you didn't find it then create ur own one......  i dont understand u exactly but maybe the following steps may help you

1- search for your template.php file
  * if you didn't find it then create ur own one in your theme folder
2- search for urthemename_theme() function in your template.php file 
  * if you found it then you can modify it... if you don't you can create ur own function
  as the following

```
function omega_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'user_register' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'user-register', // this is the name of the template
    ),
  );
}
```

3- search for user_register.tpl.php file in ur theme files...if u didn't find it then create 
   your own one and put the following code inside it

```
<div id="registration_form">
  <div class="field">
    <?php
      print drupal_render($form['account']['name']); // prints the username field
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
      print drupal_render($form['account']['pass']); // print the password field
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
        print drupal_render($form['submit']); // print the submit button
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i dont know what you mean by template.tpl.php file...i think you mean template.php
i hope that help you