# Customize login block in Omega theme (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to customize Omega theme in Drupal 7.
I want to customize user-login-block, to render this block in "User Bar Second" region; I'm able to move the block in that region, but I want to display the element horizontally.
I have read to create a function named MYTHEME_theme in template.php and create a template file in templates directory named user-login-block.tpl.php.

I have follewed various tutorial and example in internet, but I can't write a php code to fullfilment my needs.

Thanks in advance, Mauro

Answer (score 0):

if u wanna display the login form horizontally there is no need of writing any new function .. just change the template rendering and so some css changes

Comment: Thank, this is the way I'm following, but I can't figured out which template I have to customize. In the code examples I have found, it is said to override HOOK_theme function in template.php and create a brand new BLOCK-TO-CUSTOMIZE.tpl.php in the templates directory. I'm using the Omega theme and succesfully create a sub-theme structure; I'm working with this sub-theme. I must copy a *.tpl.php file from base Omega theme templates folder, but the question is: wich template I must use to customize login?

Comment: hey check this two links it may help you..
http://drupal.org/node/1167712
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132589/theme-user-registration-page-in-drupal-6-with-an-omega-subtheme

Comment: Thank, I had already seen those links but I wasn't able to made it works. I will give them another try.